# pascal based nvidia graphic card with GDDR5x and less than 160W power consumption

Tags: graphics-cards

With nvidia, manufacturers makes small changes to the original design : this is things like the clock speed or the memory size.

I want a gtx nvidia card based on the pascal micro‑architecture : this means I want :

- an underclocked GeForce 1080 which consumes less than 160W
- **Or** a Geforce 1070 which uses GDDR5x memory.

Comment: Of course, it is possible I’m wrong and that such modifications aren’t possible. I want nvidia, because their Windows driver is the only one which have an option to force trilinear filtering in all games.

Comment: Have you done any research into potential cards on your own?

Comment: @NZKshatriya : yes, and my idea is such manufacturer modifications doesn’t exist. But given some manufacturers overclock their products, many their exists an underclocked 1080.

Comment: The lowest power consumption that I can find is 180w.  What wattage is your current PSU and how much wattage do your components currently draw?  Generally, you want a little wiggle room between what you are drawing, and the max rating on the PSU.

Comment: @NZKshatriya : I have a 430W power supply. I have a 80W Intel cpu and 2 hard drives. I have no wattmetter, so I don’t know exactly what I consume at maximum. My cpu is a 4 cores one, but I have no multi threaded games so the cpu will never use 80W. did you found anything for a GDDR5x base 1070 ?

Comment: Not one.  From what I can tell GDDR5x starts with the 1080s.  The lowest wattage rating I could find was 180w(+) and suggested a minimum of a 500w PSU.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50923/discussion-between-user2284570-and-nzkshatriya).

Comment: You could force a lower wattage limit with a overclocking utility. It is very, very unlikely that you'll find a GPU that's clocked lower than stock, in a 3rd party card or otherwise.

Comment: @Alpha3031 : do you know such utility on Linux ?

Comment: I believe you'd use [nvidia-smi](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/6_0/rel/gdk/nvidia-smi.331.38.pdf), but you should probably check with Nvidia suport whether it supports power limiting on the GTX 1080, and to the extent that you need it to. Else, you're looking at flashing the card's BIOS.

Comment: @Alpha3031 Or he could end up looking at volt-modding.......but for the inverse of what volt-modding is intended for........

Comment: What is the reason of 160W limit?

Comment: @Agent_L : I don’t want any device *(computer related or not)* to consume too much electricity. So I don’t want to upgrade my 430 power supply.

Comment: @user2284570 a 430W PSU doesn't consume 430W all the time. It only consumes as much as the computer needs at the moment (+about 20% for loses). So putting a 500W will not make the computer use 70W more. If you want to save electricity, look for 80Plus certified PSU, it has smaller loses, especially 80Plus Gold or 80Plus Platinium. But most importantly is that good 430W PSU will have no problem running a 180W gpu + 80W cpu. The "500W recommended" is because there are so many shitty PSUs out there, labeled as 400 but delivering barely 200. Post what exactly PSU you have.

Comment: @Agent_L : yes I known it. But I simply want to never consume so much.

Comment: @user2284570 My point is that 500W computer with 80+ platinum CPU consumes less power than 400W computer with poor PSU. And you can always buy a GTX1080 and underclock it for less power.

Comment: @Agent_L : I don’t have a poor power supply and I thought undercloking doesn’t work on Linux.

Comment: @user2284570 It's the existence of overwhelming amount of shitty PSUs that forces nVidia to grossly overstate PSU requirements. State make an model of your PSU so I can tell you if it can carry a 1080 without breaking a sweat or if you can shave off some watts by getting a better one. Sorry, I didn't noticed the Linux requirement.

Comment: @Agent_L : that’s also why I would have no problem at using a Geforce 1070 despite the nvidia minimum 500W ᴘꜱᴜ requirement. One thing which is rare is that my ᴘꜱᴜ supports Intel® ᴄ7 states.

Comment: @user2284570 You got completely sidetracked by marketing. In desktop with pcie graphics, c7 cannot be entered at all, best you can do is c6. This way or another, it's rather pointless, because it means the machine is still running at 1% of the power. Even if the PSU can run at such low power (which means "c7 compatible") the efficiency goes down so hard it's pretty much irrelevant if the computer draws 5 or 10W. No PSU can run at 1% without wasting twice as much. If you want to actually save power then hibernate. C6/c7 are useful only in laptops, when the top power is like 60W, then c7 is 10%.